# Как сделать автоматическое назначение текущего пользователя в качестве автора при создании поста?

Tags: python, django

Как сделать автоматическое назначение текущего пользователя в качестве автора при создании поста?
Сейчас работает только если выбирать вручную автора публикации.

форма:

```
from django import forms
from publication.models import Userpublication

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(label='',widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'content_toggle app-textarea',
                                                                'utofocus': 'true',
                                                                'maxlength': '250',
                                                                'placeholder': 'Что у вас нового?',
                                                                'required': True}))

    class Meta:
        model = Userpublication
        fields = ['content', 'author'] 
        labels = {
            'Content': False,
        }
```

вьюха:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Создаем форму, передавая в нее POST-данные и текущего пользователя
        form = PostForm(request.POST, initial={'author': request.user})
        
        # Проверяем валидность формы
        if form.is_valid():
            # Сохраняем пост в базе данных
            form.save()
            
            # Перенаправляем пользователя на главную страницу
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        # Если запрос GET, создаем экземпляр формы без данных из запроса
        form = PostForm(initial={'author': request.user})
    
    # Получаем список опубликованных постов
    post_lists = Userpublication.objects.all()

    # Передаем форму и список постов в контекст шаблона
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'post_lists': post_lists,
    }

    # Отрисовываем шаблон с переданным контекстом
    return render(request, 'twippie/home.html', context)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой способ работает.

Но как только в форме убираю fields 'author', а 'content' остается, то появляется вот такая ошибка:

> Internal Server Error: /feed/ Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute return
> self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute return
> super().execute(query, params) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
> publication_userpublication. author_id
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner response =
> get_response(request) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response response =
> wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapper_view return
> view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\django\vers0.0.3.1\vers0.2.5 04\twippie_project\twippie\views.py",
> li ne 16, in create_post form.save() File
> "C:\django\vers0.0.3.1\vers0.2.5
> 04\twippie_project\usercreatepost\forms. py", line 29, in save
> instance.save() File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\models\base.py", line 822, in save self.save_base( File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\models\base.py", line 909, in save_base updated =
> self._save_table( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\models\base.py", line 1067, in _save_table results =
> self._do_insert( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\models\base.py", line 1108, in _do_insert return
> manager._insert( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method return
> getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\models\query.py", line 1845, in _insert return
> query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1823, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params) File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\utils.py", line 122, in execute return
> super().execute(sql, params) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute return
> self._execute_with_wrappers( ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in _execute with
> self.db.wrap_database_errors: File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\utils.py", line 91, in **exit** raise
> dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute return
> self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages
> django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute return
> super().execute(query, params) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
> publication_userpubl ication.author_id

а в браузере:

> IntegrityError at /feed/ NOT NULL constraint failed:
> publication_userpublication.author_id

Answer (score 0):

Решил свой вопрос. Дело оказалось куда проще.

У меня одно из приложений отвечает за форму публикации и выводов постов.

Во втором приложении была добавлена точно такая же функция вьюхи.

Стоило её убрать, и всё заработало.